# What's the name of "the mininum value of $x^TPx$ from the points on a hyperplane to the origin"?

Tags: linear-algebra, positive-definite

Suppose $P\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ is a positive definite symmetrical matrix. $F\in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$, $g\in \mathbb{R}^{m}$, $n > m$. The set $S=\{x|Fx=g\}$ is an $n-m$ dimensional hyperplane.

Is there a name for the following stuff?

$$min\{\sqrt{x^TPx}|x\in S\}$$

It would be the Euler distance from $S$ to the origin point if $P=I^{n\times n}$.

Answer (score 0):

It is the [Mahalanobis distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahalanobis_distance). Formally, given a test point $x$ and a probability distribution $\mathcal{D}$ with mean $\mu$ and covariance $C$, the Mahalanobis distance between $x$ and $\mathcal{D}$ is measured as
$$
\text{dist}_M(x, \mathcal{D}) = \sqrt{(x-\mu)^TC^{-1}(x-\mu)}
$$
Because $P$ in the question is positive definite, its inverse exists and $P^{-1}$ serves as $C$ above.

Comment: Mahalanobis distance measures the MEAN distance while the question is the MINIMUM distance. I don't think they are same.

Comment: @iuradz You in fact want to find a point in $S$ such that its Mahalanobis distance to the origin is minimized.

Comment: Exactly. But I cannot find a phrase to describe it. It's not the Mahalanobis distance from $S$ to the origin, since the Mahalanobis distance is infinity. Can I say it's the minimized Mahalanobis distance?

Comment: @iuradz I think it is similar to the case of Euclidean distance. Basicly, the Euclidean distance between $S$ and the origin is defined as the minimum distance of a point $x \in S$ and the origin. But in your case, I think it is better to say explicitly that it is the minimum Mahalanobis distance between a point in $S$ and the origin.